# Oracle select dates based on year returning inconsistent results

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I'm getting a peculiar problem with an Oracle view I've modified. The idea is I have a base table that stores all election candidates and also has an election date column, telling us what election this candidate was part of, like so.

```
NAME       | ELECTION_DATE
---------------------------
John Smith | 01-APR-2011
Alan Cooper| 02-MAY-2013
```

The ELECTION_DATE column is stored as a date. We constructed 2 views for 2011 and 2013, using the following statment for 2011.

```
where election_date >= to_date(2011,'yyyy') and election_date < to_date(2012,'yyyy')
```

Which we thought would pick up just the John Smith record above, but it didn't. The peculiar thing was that when we did this for the 2013 view.

```
where election_date >= to_date(2013,'YYYY') and election_date < to_date(2014,'YYYY')
```

It DID get just the Alan Cooper record. Even more peculiar is that if we did this for the 2011 view.

```
where election_date >= to_date(2010,'yyyy') and election_date < to_date(2011,'yyyy')
```

We got just the John Smith record and not the Alan Cooper record, which is what we wanted but not what we expected.

We then changed them both to between statements and they behaved exactly the same i.e. between 2010 and 2011 got the John Smith record, between 2011 and 2012 got nothing and between 2013 and 2014 got the Alan Cooper record.

Whilst I was writing this my colleague managed to fix it by using this more explicit statement.

```
where election_date between  '01-JAN-2011' AND '01-JAN-2012'
```

But I still want to know why the above statements still worked so strangely? Something I am missing about using to_date functions for just years maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you look at what your `to_date()` functions actually produced?

```
select to_date(2011, 'yyyy'), to_date(2012, 'yyyy'), to_date(2013, 'yyyy')
from dual;

TO_DATE(2011,'Y TO_DATE(2012,'Y TO_DATE(2013,'Y
--------------- --------------- ---------------
01-MAY-11       01-MAY-12       01-MAY-13
```

Based on those dates the results you got are correct.

If you don't specify the month and day then they default to the first day of the current month, although the time defaults to midnight. From the [documentation for date time literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062), which is the only official reference I can find for this behaviour:

> If you specify a date value without a time component, then the default
>   time is midnight (00:00:00 or 12:00:00 for 24-hour and 12-hour clock
>   time, respectively). If you specify a date value without a date, then
>   the default date is the first day of the current month.

If you're going to use

```
where election_date between  '01-JAN-2011' AND '01-JAN-2012'
```

... then you should still use `to_date()` as you're relying on a default date format mask that might change in the future, and is session dependent. `between` is also inclusive, so using that your 2011 view would include an election held on 01-Jan-2012, which probably isn't what you want, so using `>=` and `<` is maybe safe. Alternatively use date literals:

```
where election_date >= date '2011-01-01' and election_date < date '2012-01-01'
```

Comment: This line - If you don't specify the month and day then they default to the first day of the current month - explains the problem! I assumed (wrongly) that a to_date function with just a year would default to 01/01 not 01/{current_month}. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try extracting the year as a VARCHAR2 and doing the comparison

```
select * from table where to_char(ELECTION_DATE, 'yyyy') = `2011` 
or to_char(ELECTION_DATE, 'yyyy') = '2012'
```

Comment: This will work, but render any indices useless - doing it the other way round makes more sense IMHO.

Comment: Unless it's going to be a very common operation on this one table, warranting a function-based index.