# Where should I start learning Highcharts JS?

Tags: javascript, css, html, highcharts

I am beginner and do not know much right now, but I know a bit of HTML5 and CSS.

I have to generate interactive graphs by fetching data from an Excel file (on a password-protected website), which get updated every minute and generate a new file every month.

I am trying to use [Highcharts JS](http://www.highcharts.com/) but I do not understand them.

What should I learn first for this project?

Comment: Do you know JavaScript at all?

Comment: Note also that Stack Overflow is designed for more specific programming questions (i.e. "I'm trying to create a line graph with Highcharts JS, but the line won't draw on the graph"). Feel free to come back with more specific questions when you're writing code.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn what kind of questions you can ask, and how best to ask them.

Comment: I really want to ask questions but i will not anymore whenever i ask questions they marked me as (-4)or something thats rude if you don't want to help then why this..Thanks @Paul D. Waite

Comment: No i dont know javascript at all.. @PaulD.Waite

Comment: @user2413421 It's more about what you are asking. StackOverflow is for very specific questions about particular programming problems, rather than 'I need to do this'. I think -5 for your question is a little unfair, but with the volume of questions on here people very quickly chuck away ones that don't necessarily have an answer. We encourage you to ask questions, but don't make them open ended. Take Pauls advice above and you'll have no problem here.

Comment: @user2413421: yup, Rob’s pretty much nailed it. Anyone can answer questions on Stack Overflow, and we’re all volunteering our time when doing so, so when a question looks like it took little effort to ask, but will take a lot of effort to answer, we don’t like it. If you can make your questions more clear, spelled-out and specific, the effort ratio feels a lot better.

Comment: @user2413421: I do understand how unfriendly the site must feel to you at the moment. The best advice I can offer is to look at @RobQuincey’s two questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315108 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982777) — they’re very good examples.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You're trying to make up for stealing my answer points aren't you.. :) user2413421 I think this very conversation/banter that is going on between us shows how friendly we all really are. Stick with SO and you'll soon be a massive reputation whore like me :)

Comment: Thanks for your nice comments , I really appreciate it @RobQuincey Quinceynd ... I have started javascript basics now..

Comment: @PaulD. Waite Thank for your humbleness as well... :)... I will be more careful and be more specific , I asked this because i didn't know what is specific right now ...

Comment: @user2413421: ah gotcha - the human language barrier is a big issue too. Naw you're very welcome, it's not easy when you're new to a Stack site. It took me over a year to get a question voted up over on serverfault.com.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I have posted a new question, I hope its better than the last one.. Thanks I am going through the same ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highcharts JS is a JavaScript library, so you'll need to learn at least a bit of JavaScript in order to use it properly.

If you need a JavaScript introduction, you might want to try the Mozilla Developer Network introduction, it looks pretty readable:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Highcharts JS itself looks like it's got pretty comprehensive and friendly documentation too:

- http://www.highcharts.com/docs

Comment: Yeah, shoulda mentioned in mine that getting the hang of even basic JavaScript might help :P

Comment: @RobQuincey: heh, maybe - it's hard to tell from the question whether the OP knows JavaScript, or doesn't yet know what JavaScript is.

Comment: Ahhh he doesn't deserve the answer, he's already got enough reputation!! Tee hee.

Comment: @RobQuincey: shoulda mentioned basic JavaScript, Rob. Rookie mistake.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Bah! Foiled again!

Comment: @RobQuincey: it’s a cruel and unforgiving world. I have voted up some of your other answers to make up for it: looking forward to seeing you join the >1K club.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Too true. Oh you are too kind. I'm chasing 1k on here and GIS.SE. I've gotten very little actual work done for a while now...

Comment: @RobQuincey: Stack Exchange counts I reckon. It's [sharpening the saw](https://www.stephencovey.com/7habits/7habits-habit7.php).

Comment: http://docs.highcharts.com/ link is broken :(

Answer (score 5):

Well their own help docs are a good place to start - http://www.highcharts.com/docs

Specifically the 'Your first chart' section - http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart

They've also done a dead tree version (a 'book' to most people) - http://www.packtpub.com/learning-highcharts-for-javascript-data-visualization/book

And just because you don't understand it straight away doesn't matter. Just go through tutorials following instructions exactly, then from there you can start tweaking the examples you created for you own needs. Just go for it! The best way to learn is by experimentation!

Comment: http://docs.highcharts.com/ link is broken :(